# What is the difference between grafting and bonding in reference to polymers?

Tags: polymers

I'm reading research papers and some keep mentioning grafting of polymers. Looked it up in wikipedia and it talks about adsorbing polymers, and im not sure what the difference is. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafting a polymer B on a polymer A is attaching  polymer B to the linear backbone of polymer A (co-polymer).
If A and B are identical, we obtain a branched polymer (Homopolymer).

Answer (score 0):

Grafting of polymers is not the process you would think it is. Grafting of polymers means to grow branches periodically and regularly off the backbone on an existing polymer. This is can create dendrites, or more relevant, brush structures which have surprising biological properties (in vivo of course).

This is a process not a "thing" per se, if that helps.